# Text transparent through parrent div

Tags: css, canvas, opacity, transparent, clip

talented and awesome people of StackOverflow.
I need a solution or help to find one for my particular problem.

I have a div, with a background image, over it I have another div with background color rgba(red, .9), and on it, I have a giant text title that should be transparent through its parent, and actually see through the image on the main parent div

```
<div class="grand-parent" style="background-image: url(random)">
    <div class="parent" background="rgba(red, .9)">
        <h1> MY GIANT TITLE </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

can this be done with clipping, or masking, or mix-blend-mode (I didn't make it), but the point is, though the text should be a pure white color going over the red div, and actually you can see the image through the text, like text having opacity...

Can I see through red div somehow? 
if anyone knows how to do it with canvas, I would appreciate a demo. Thanks and sorry for a non-visual explanation.